# What is an efficient design to store variables for different product lines in ER database?

Tags: database-design, mysql

This question is about refactoring existing database design.

My data flow is

1. User generates some data for product lines A, B, C
2. Data is saved into the database once
3. Data is later retrieved multiple times

Current design has 3 tables:  `data_a`, `data_b`, `data_c`, where each table shares some columns that are identical (in name) and some that are unique to that product line.

For example, same-name columns in each table are `weight`, `unit_system` and a few others.  The differently-named columns have values that represent physical quantities of the particular product line.  Those are named using various alphanumeric identifiers, like `a`, `b5`, `e2`, and there is a different set of them for different product line.  Those sets can share elements, i.e. `b5` can be in more than one table, but then something like `t1` can be in one table but not the others.

**Problem**

Currently when there is a need to add some value say `x9` to product line a, I would update the database schema for `data_a` to have column `x9`.  I make the values of x9 as 0 for existing column rows, and new records will begin to populate with the actual `x9` values.  Then I update the code in relevant places to insert `x9` into the table or retrieve it from the table.

**Existing design**

```
data_a(id, item_id, shared, different_a)
data_b(id, item_id, shared, different_b)
data_c(id, item_id, shared, different_c)
```

[image]

where `shared` columns is a group of columns that is identical in each table, while `different` are columns that are disjointed in theory, as they represent 3 different product lines, but actually may share some similarly-named elements, as some variable names are the same for different product lines.

**Proposed design**

This is where I'm struggling.  Because I don't see a good clean design that is also efficient.  I wanted to get rid of the need to alter database schema every time there is a new variable added to a product line.  And I believe I can do that, but I also want to make an efficient design, and I don't see one.

But this is my try:

Keep primary key, foreign key and shared column names in a single table:

```
data(id, item_id, shared)
```

Create a single table for variables only (variables are ones found in `different` sets):

```
data_variables(id, item_id, data_id, variable, value)
```

[image]

I am not sure if this design will be worth the trouble, because ... I will actually be storing more data - all the extra `data_id` or all the extra `item_id` values for each variable name.  There are 15 to 30 variable names for each product line.  I will be storing 15 to 30 `item_id` (or `data_id`) fields in the new design `data_variables` table, where in the old design there was only one `item_id` value per table row.

**Question:**

Is there a more efficient design that also does not require changes in schema design for every addition/deletion/modification of variable name in a product line?  Might it be best to stick with existing design despite the trouble of altering schema when needing to add new variables?

**Using JSON for variable "different" fields**

```
one_data_table(id, item_id, product_line, shared, json_encoded_value_pairs);
```

**Decision to not use EAV (Entity–attribute–value) Model**

In my case Entities change very rarely if at all (on the order of years), and attributes change rarely as well, on the order of months or more.  As such, reworking the database design to use EAV is probably not a good fit for my case.

That aside, I am still debating on my JSON Design.

Comment: I hesitate to suggest it, but if you have many similar tables, and those tables have some attributes in common, but others that are changing, you might want to look at EAV -- [Entity-Attribute-Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). It's one of those things that can either be a perfect fit for your problem, or it can become a perfect nightmare for you and those who come after you. WordPress uses it heavily. It makes it easy to add attributes to Posts, but with large tables it can also make things ssssslllooowwww.

Comment: So far I just have 3 (or 6 actually).  Maybe in a few years there will be 8 or 10.  I hesitate to uproot everything, that is change all the existing tables to end up with a mess of things... I am thinking maybe having 3 entities as in my case is not so bad right now.  I am pondering however if I should do something like `one_data_table(id, item_id, product_line, shared, json_value_pairs);`  That might actually be a good idea

Comment: Why not just move `shared` up into `item`? This might be easiest, unless you foresee the number of tables (table_a, table_b, table_c) being more variable than presented here.

Comment: well it is possible... I am not sure if it will make sense conceptually on high level.  `item` stores data relating to items on an invoice, things like price, description, etc., while `data` is to store values for an engineering drawing, things like length, weight, etc.  But even let's suppose I do that...  what about the `different` elements? Will those have to use the EAV model?

Comment: @Dennis: Will they need to use EAV? Maybe, maybe not. EAV it something I'd consider if the rate of change and churn is so high that modifying the schema (and all supporting code) just takes too long to keep things in sync, or the system needs to be *extremely* flexible - enough so that users can add new attributes to things on-the-fly. But EAV can add many other complications so I wouldn't go down that road unless it was necessary (...and I admit that it is sometimes necessary).

Answer (score 3):

So I understand you don't want to have fields from `data_*` in `item` because they're not really the same thing. So how about something like this schema below? It's similar to your original design, but it adds a new `Common_data` table between the `item` table and the `data_*` tables.

```
Item
----
 - item_id
 - (other item-focused fields)

Common_Data
-----------
 - common_data_id
 - item_id - FK to item.item_id
 - shared_field_1
 - shared_field_2
 - (many fields that are already shared in data_a, data_b, and data_c)
 - data_type (can be "data a", "data b", "data c")

data_a
------
 - data_a_id
 - common_data_id  - FK to common_data.common_data_id
 - different_a

data_b
------
 - data_b_id
 - common_data_id  - FK to common_data.common_data_id
 - different_b

data_c
------
 - data_c_id
 - common_data_id  - FK to common_data.common_data_id
 - different_c
```

Pros:

- simplifies your `shared` data, moving it all up to a common data table.
- similar to existing design - maybe some of your existing code can be salvaged
- new `shared` data only needs to be added to one place.
- simpler to implement.

Cons:

- might not be flexible enough if you think you will soon have `data_d`, `data_e`, etc... and then remove older ones.
- still requires schema (and possibly code) changes when new data_*-specific fields are added.

I'd avoid going the EAV route unless you really *need* the flexibility of it.

Comment: thanks.  I think EAV route as "fun" as it looked probably is a no go for reasons you've mentioned.  There is no need to change parameters on the fly.  I think breaking up or merging the tables though will end up being inconvenient or confusing in the long run - code-wise I will have to write data that's conceptually in the same group to different tables.  While more efficient I am not convinced to myself that I should change my existing design.